# Telerik RadGrid ExportToCSV is not working in Chrome

Tags: asp.net, csv, telerik, export, radgrid

Telerik RadGrid ExportToCSV was used in my RadGrid, but it's not working in Chrome, but it's working in FF and IE 7, 8, 9. It was working on Chrome before too.

The problem is that instead of exporting the file it shows the data in the browser. I don't need to see data in the browser, that's what the grid is used for. I would like to just export my CSV file.

If I am not mistaken, some changes were made in Chrome recently.

Did anybody else meet this Telerik bug before? Is there a solution to this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    With _radGrid
        For Each col In .MasterTableView.Columns
            If (col.GetType.Name.Equals("GridButtonColumn")) Then
                CType(col, GridButtonColumn).Visible = False
            ElseIf (col.GetType.Name.Equals("GridEditCommandColumn")) Then
                CType(col, GridEditCommandColumn).Visible = False
            ElseIf (col.GetType.Name.Equals("GridHyperLinkColumn")) Then
                CType(col, GridHyperLinkColumn).Visible = False
            End If
        Next
        .ExportSettings.IgnorePaging = True
        .ExportSettings.FileName = ExportFileName
        .ExportSettings.IgnorePaging = True
        .ExportSettings.OpenInNewWindow = True
        .MasterTableView.CurrentPageIndex = 0
        .MasterTableView.ExportToCSV()
    End With
```

where ExportFileName is a string.